# What am I doing wrong while mining in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm new to this game. I'm mining in 12th and 13th layers by making 2x2 tunnels, and have made several 50-60 block long tunnels. The problem is so far I'm only able to find iron, redstone, coal, lapis lazuli, but no diamonds and only a little gold. So, my question is why am I not able to find reasonable amount of gold and diamond. Is the problem my technique of mining or am I searching in wrong layers? What is the best way to mine gold and diamond in Minecraft? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Persistence my friend. I recently had to mine 300 in all four directions before finding any diamonds.

Comment: Agreed.  It's all about persistence and patience.

Comment: Maybe try mining from 11 to 16 layered underground areas.